# Not able to run oracle database 12 on kubernetes with persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes, oracle12.2

#### Hi I am trying to run oracle db 12 on k8s, with a persistent volume, but it's throwing the error below. please what I am missing

- I have created a pv/pvc, mount path /opt/oracle/oradata
- permissions to uid 54321 are provided

  ```
  Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracledb-c6867b8cf-v6bnf/listener/alert/log.xml
    Listening Endpoints Summary...
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
      (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
    The listener supports no services
    The command completed successfully
    [WARNING] [DBT-10328] Specified GDB Name (ORCLCDB) may have a potential conflict with an already existing database on the system.
       ACTION: Specify a different GDB Name that does not conflict with existing databases on the system.
    [FATAL] [DBT-10317] Specified SID Name (ORCLCDB) already exists.
       ACTION: Specify a different SID Name that does not already exist.
    SQL>    ALTER SYSTEM SET control_files='/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/control01.ctl' scope=spfile
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
    Process ID: 0
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


    SQL>    ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ORCLPDB1 SAVE STATE
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
    Process ID: 0
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


    SQL> BEGIN DBMS_XDB_CONFIG.SETGLOBALPORTENABLED (TRUE); END;

    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
    Process ID: 0
    Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


    SQL> Disconnected
    mv: cannot stat '/opt/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileORCLCDB.ora': No such file or directory
    mv: cannot stat '/opt/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1/dbs/orapwORCLCDB': No such file or directory
    The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
    #####################################
    ########### E R R O R ###############
    DATABASE SETUP WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL!
    Please check output for further info!
    ########### E R R O R ###############
  ```

please what I am missing. can be related to env

where can I find more logs

Comment: what error, please paste here?

Comment: can you also paste the oracle docker image(name, version)? and, i guess, you should firstly mount pvc to elsewhere(not oracle install dir), after oracle startup, you modify oracle database persistent location to your pvc dir.

Comment: Here is the version: 12.2.0.1-ee-ready. Itried to do so, but once I change the mount path I got the same error